# Adding hook to XML::Compile::WSDL11 to modify WSSE header

Tags: xml, perl, soap, wss

I'm using the `XML::Compile` suite to work with a `SOAP API` that uses `WSSE` security with a digest password generated with `sha1`.  Unfortunately the password digest protocol that `XML::Compile::WSS::BasicAuth` uses is

> sha1_base64(encode utf8 => "$nonce$created$password").'='

where `$nonce` and `$password` are text values and `$created` is a timestamp, while the `API` I'm working with uses the digest generator

> sha1_base64($nonce.$created.sha1($password)).'='

I figured I could fix this by rewritinng the password using a hook, as in

> $wsdl->addHook(type=> 'wsse::PasswordString',replace => \&replace_pwd);

Since the curent `CPAN` documentation does not clearly specify hook call syntax, I relied on the module author's comments at `http://grokbase.com/t/sc/xml-compile/1283vscwxz/need-help-with-xml-compile-translate-writer-and-attributes-with-namespace`.  However the callback function `replace_pwd()` is never called with the result that the original (wrong) password generated by `XML::Compile::WSS::BasicAuth` continues to get sent.

How do I get this to work?

TIA.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem recently and ended up creating an instance of XML::Compile::WSS::BasicAuth, setting XCWB_login with the code copied from XML::Compile::WSS::BasicAuth->prepareWriting modified to generate the password string as I needed, and passing that BasicAuth instance as the wsse_Security option to XML::Compile::Schema->call.

This is super lame, but the only way that I found to solve this problem using these libraries.